# Convert two column data frame to numeric matrix

Tags: r, matrix, transformation

I have the following data:

```
A    B
1    101
1    102
3    104
4    104
```

And would like to transform it into this:

```
     101   102   104
1      1     1     0
3      0     0     1
4      0     0     1
```

What is this transformation called and what kind of package should I be looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xtabs` from base R to do this:

```
df <-  read.table(text="A    B
+ 1    101
+ 1    102
+ 3    104
+ 4    104", header=T)

xtabs(~ A + B, df)

#   B
#A   101 102 104
#  1   1   1   0
#  3   0   0   1
#  4   0   0   1
```

Another way of doing it would be to use `table`:

```
table(df)

#   B
#A   101 102 104
#  1   1   1   0
#  3   0   0   1
#  4   0   0   1
```